# Send ClientID and Secret in Authorization header ( angularjs )

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, spring-boot, restful-authentication

I am building a simple Client App which is talking to a rest api and getting information about the user. I am implementing **Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow** of [OAuth](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2/grants/password.html).

I have been struggling with how to send my client ID and Secret in Authorization header in an angular app.

I have built an authService and an interceptor service to handle my login.

my `app.js`

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('AngularAuthApp', ['ngRoute', 'LocalStorageModule', 'angular-loading-bar']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
        controller: "homeController",
        templateUrl: "/views/home.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/login", {
        controller: "loginController",
        templateUrl: "/views/login.html"
    });


    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" });
});

app.run(['authService', function (authService) {
    authService.fillAuthData();
}]);


app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
});
```

this is my `authService.js`

```
app.factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', function ($http, $q, localStorageService) {

    var serviceBase = 'http://url/oauth/';
    var authServiceFactory = {};

    var _authentication = {
        isAuth: false,
        userName : ""
    };

    var _login = function (loginData) {

        var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password ;
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post(serviceBase + 'token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).success(function (response) {

            localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName });

            _authentication.isAuth = true;
            _authentication.userName = loginData.userName;

            deferred.resolve(response);

        }).error(function (err, status) {
            _logOut();
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;

    };

  authServiceFactory.login = _login;
  return authServiceFactory;

}]);
```

and `authInterceptorService.js`

```
app.factory('authInterceptorService', ['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', function ($q, $location, localStorageService) {

    var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

    var _request = function (config) {

        config.headers = config.headers || {};

        var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
        if (authData) {
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
        }

        return config;
    }

    var _responseError = function (rejection) {
        if (rejection.status === 401) {
            $location.path('/login');
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }

    authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
    authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;

    return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
}]);
```

My curl request which throws me an access token is

```
curl -X POST -vu sampleapp:samplekey http://sampleurl/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=pwd&username=uname&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=samplekey&client_id=sampleapp"
```

So, I am guessing that I need to send the clientID and clientSecret but am not sure how to implement it or where to add it. I have looked into documents saying that we might need to add to authorization header but I don't think I'm doing it right. Also, do I need to encode it or anything ? This is not a JWT token but a simple token. Do I also need to send in the `scope` ?

I am getting a 401 error of `Full authentication is required to access this resource` as of now.